# pass optional function as parameter to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Options of how I want to call a function:

```
myAjax("http://ajaxurl.com", { prop: val }, function(resp) { alert(resp); });
```

or

```
function handleSuccess(resp) { alert(resp); }
myAjax("http://ajaxurl.com", { prop: val }, handleSuccess);
```

or

```
myAjax("http://ajaxurl.com", { prop: val }, null);
```

or

```
myAjax("http://ajaxurl.com", { prop: val }); // param not even provided
```

How can I handle this on the myAjax function definition?  Something like this...?

```
function myAjax(url, jsonData, successFunc) {
  $.ajax({
    ... all the necessary ajax stuff that normally goes here
    , success: function(response) {
      // custom myAjax success handling goes here. this must happen before optionally-passed-in successFunc gets executed

      // what goes here? this?
      if (typeof successFunc != 'undefined' && successFunc != null) {
        successFunc(response);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I tried something like the above, but, it did not call the success function.  Do I need to check if successFunc is a function?

Thanks!

Comment: `typeof successFunc == 'function'`

Comment: instead of or in addition to? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing against unknown types, verify that the function is indeed a function:

```
if (typeof successFunc == 'function') {
    successFunc(response);
}
```

Your current code does not prevent `successFunc` from being run, though. Make sure that the AJAX request is successfully handled (no errors no cross-domain restrictions).

Since your code doesn't event reach the point of calling `successFunc`, it's likely that an error is generated before `if (typeof ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Testing that the typeof successFunc is "function" will do the trick:

```
function myAjax(url, jsonData, successFunc) {
  $.ajax({
    ... all the necessary ajax stuff that normally goes here
    , success: function(response) {
      // custom myAjax success handling goes here. this must happen before optionally-passed-in successFunc gets executed

      // what goes here? this?
      if (typeof successFunc === 'function') {
        successFunc(response);
      }
    }
  });
}
```